# CodeIgniter Session - i am not getting my userdata in other controller

Tags: codeigniter

here is my code to set session

```
$login_data = array('logged_in'=>TRUE, 'user_id'=>$userid);
$this->session->set_userdata($login_data);
redirect('dashboard');
```

above code creates a new entry in ci_session table in my db and it has logged_in value

In dashboard controller i am checking session. Below is my code in dashboard controller

```
function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        if(!$logged_in){
            redirect("welcome");
        }
    }
```

In above constructor block i am not getting the value of logged_in.

I have also tried to print all my userdata using `var_dump($this->session->all_userdata)` but all I get is an empty string.

Please tell me what could be the reason behing it. I also searched for cookie but i didn't find that in my computer. below is my config detail

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: I have solved my problem. I just forgot to change my Cookie Related Variables in config.

Comment: Then close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I just forgot to change my Cookie Related Variables in config. –

Comment: u saved me bro +1 :)

Comment: What you changed?

Comment: I think this should be accepted as an answer as this answer not saying anything about how problem is solved. This problem does exist when u have default codeigniter config.php file

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is being you're doing this in the __construct method which is executed when the class is initialized - before the page is even loaded and your sessions data is set.

```
$logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if(!$logged_in){
        redirect("welcome");
    }
```

Will work if you add in into the beginning of the page method.

Comment: No it is not like that. It works in constructor also. I have soved my problem. I just forgot to change my cookie related variables.

Answer (score 0):

Is the library being autoloaded? Check `config/autoload.php`:

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation');`

Or call `$this->load->library('session');` right before using the class.